# How to add a button that will make calculations from a table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, html-table

I have been trying to add both a row and a column to a table, which I think I have finally managed. Now I am trying to create a button using javascript beneath the table that will calculate the sum of each row in the new column and will calculate the the last two columns in the new row. I have tried various ways of creating the button but I can't seem to make it work, and as you can see I don't know how to create the code that will make the calculations that I need.

Here is my code:

```
function addLoadEvent(func) 
{
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') 
    {
        window.onload = func;
    } 
    else 
    {
        window.onload = function() 
        {
            oldonload();
            func();
        }
    }
}

function addRow() 
{
    if (!document.getElementById) return false;
    var table = document.getElementById("pricetable");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    row.setAttribute("id","sumrow");

    var cell1 = row.insertCell();
    var cell2 = row.insertCell();
    var cell3 = row.insertCell();
    var cell4 = row.insertCell();
    var cell5 = row.insertCell();
}

function addColumn()
{
    if (!document.getElementById) return false;
    if (!document.createElement) return false;

    var tHead = document.getElementById("pricetable").tHead;
    for (var h=0; h<tHead.rows.length; h++) 
    {
        var newTHead = document.createElement("th");
        tHead.rows[h].appendChild(newTHead);
        newTHead.innerHTML = "Sum";
    }

    var tBody = document.getElementById("pricetable").tBodies[0];
    for (var i=0; i<tBody.rows.length; i++) 
    {
        var newCell = tBody.rows[i].insertCell(-1);
    }
}

function addButton() 
{
    var btn = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "button");
    input.setAttribute("name","Calc price");

    var foo = document.getElementById("pricetable");
    foo.appendChild(btn);

    btn.onclick = function()
    {
        alert ("Calulate price");
    }
}

addLoadEvent(addRow);
addLoadEvent(addColumn);
addLoadEvent(addButton);
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
 <body>
<div id ="container">
    <div id ="header">
        <h1>Electronics</h1>
    </div>
    <div id ="content">
        <h3>Our prices</h3>
        <table id ="pricetable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Article</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>23456789</td>
                <td>Phone</td>
                <td>Apple</td>
                <td>6500</td>
                <td><input type ="text" size ="3" value ="1"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>22256289</td>
                <td>Phone</td>
                <td>Samsung</td>
                <td>6200</td>
                <td><input type ="text" size ="3" value ="1"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>24444343</td>
                <td>Phone</td>
                <td>MS Lumia</td>
                <td>4200</td>
                <td><input type ="text" size ="3" value ="1"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>19856639</td>
                <td>Tablet</td>
                <td>LG</td>
                <td>4000</td>
                <td><input type ="text" size ="3" value ="1"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>39856639</td>
                <td>Tablet</td>
                <td>Dell</td>
                <td>2800</td>
                <td><input type ="text" size ="3" value ="1"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>12349862</td>
                <td>Tablet</td>
                <td>Apple</td>
                <td>3500</td>
                <td><input type ="text" size ="3" value ="1"/></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Need a fully working HTML snippet to give you an answer, but from the get go, your add button will break the table because you adding input as an child element. You need to go foo.parentNode.appendChild(btn); // assuming your table is enclosed in another dom tag.

Comment: I have managed to get the button like I want it, but I can't manage to make it sum column 5 and 6, or the rows (except the first one) when I click on the button.